# Scala: providing type information for function argument in coding time

Tags: scala, types

Here is a simplified version of the problem that I have:

```
case class HEdge[N,E](n:N, e:E)
case class ANode[N,E](head:N ,out:List[HEdge[N,E]])
object ANode{
  def apply[N,E](head:N ,out:HEdge[N,E]*):ANode[N,E] = ANode(head,out.toList)
}
```

When I want to use it with simple types it works as expected:

```
val x = ANode[String,String]("aaa", HEdge("bb","cc"))
```

I also test it with another more complicated type:

```
case class Foo[N](e:N => Boolean)
case class Bar[E](e:E => Boolean)
```

it works when I fully specify the type parameters for functions inside the `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
val y1 = ANode[Foo[String], Bar[String]](Foo[String](x => x == ""), HEdge(Foo[String](x => x == ""), Bar[String](z => z == "")))
```

but it doesn't work when I leave it to compiler to find the types:

```
val y = ANode[Foo[String], Bar[String]](Foo(x => x == ""), HEdge(Foo(x => x == ""), Bar(z => z == "")))
```

How can I force the compiler to work properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case class ANode[N,E](head:N ,out:List[HEdge[N,E]])` defines it's own `apply` which you overload and it causes ambiguity. This will compile:

```
case class HEdge[N,E](n:N, e:E)
class ANode[N,E](head:N ,out:List[HEdge[N,E]])
object ANode{
  def apply[N,E](head:N ,out:HEdge[N,E]*):ANode[N,E] = new ANode(head,out.toList)
}
case class Foo[N](e:N => Boolean)
case class Bar[E](e:E => Boolean)
val y1 = ANode[Foo[String], Bar[String]](Foo(x => x == ""), HEdge(Foo(x => x == ""), Bar(z => z == "")))
```

Comment: is there any way to keep it as a `case class` ? I need it to be case class for my pattern matches and other stuffs

Comment: Just use provided `apply` method, it's not that different from your implementation. Or if you need varargs instead of `List`, rename your `apply` to something else and use it explicitly.